# binary logistic regression with large sample size

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data, goodness-of-fit, hosmer-lemeshow-test

I try to make a binary logistic regression model from 85871 samples. I used enter method. There are seven explanatory variables and all of them have significant in Wald Test. But, in Hosmer Lemeshow Test also significant, so my model doesn't fit the data right? What can I do in order to make my model fit? Is there another goodness of fit test?

Comment: With your large sample size, you can get low p-values for the explanatory variables even if your model's explanatory power is low.

Comment: You need to read up on logistic regression, many post here which could help. A few:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18750/hosmer-lemeshow-vs-aic-for-logistic-regression   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53078/how-to-visualize-bayesian-goodness-of-fit-for-logistic-regression    For us to be able to help more, we need more information! Please read http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/  and write a better question!

Comment: Do you intend to use your model for prediction? What is your goal? Goodness of fit is pointless in a prediction setting.

Comment: Note that Hosmer-Lemeshow test is now considered obsolete:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/273999/11887