# Sensitivity equals one, specificity equals zero across multiple algorithms on two separate platforms

Tags: r, classification, python, svm, validation

We have a two group classification problem that is a giving some bizarre training results.  I have tested this in both R and Python across multiple algorithms and gotten similar results but I am including only R SVM output below.  In brief we are trying to predict group membership based on brain imaging data.  Both region of interest (17 features) and ICA loading coefficients (60 features) give the same result for this data,  with and without feature selection.

The crux of the problem is illustrated in the R output below:

Support Vector Machines with Radial Basis Function Kernel

```
544 samples<br/>
17 predictor<br/>
2 classes: 'ClassA', 'ClassB' <br/>

No pre-processing<br/>
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 5 times) <br/>
Summary of sample sizes: 490, 490, 490, 489, 490, 489, ... <br/>
Resampling results across tuning parameters:<br/>

  sigma  C    ROC        Sens       Spec       
  0.005  0.5  0.5297579  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.005  1.0  0.5422166  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.005  1.5  0.5505414  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.005  2.0  0.5511248  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.005  2.5  0.5513616  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.005  3.0  0.5503681  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.005  3.5  0.5644331  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.011  0.5  0.5469811  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.011  1.0  0.5503466  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.011  1.5  0.5683659  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.011  2.0  0.5690950  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.011  2.5  0.5722130  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.011  3.0  0.5576593  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.011  3.5  0.5688788  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.200  0.5  0.5544983  0.9990244  0.000000000<br/>
  0.200  1.0  0.5492066  0.9995122  0.000000000<br/>
  0.200  1.5  0.5492004  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.200  2.0  0.5543411  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.200  2.5  0.5461315  0.9995122  0.000000000<br/>
  0.200  3.0  0.5416475  1.0000000  0.000000000<br/>
  0.200  3.5  0.5535835  1.0000000  0.001538462<br/>
```

ROC was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final values used for the model were sigma = 0.011 and C = 2.5.

As can be seen the model sensitivity equals one but the trained model has no specificity. This is similar for all algorithms in both packages. I feel like this data is trying to tell me something but I don't know what it is, so I am looking for insight if anyone has any to offer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if you algorithm actually predicts different values? Often this issue arises when you only predict 0 or 1 for everything. in that way, all your important class cases are captures correctly and your sensitivity will be equal to 1.

example:

if you say that having cancer means cancer = 1 and is the positive category and the majority. Then your algorithm will predict 1 for everything, therefore you'll get a sensitivity of 1 (as all cancer cases were captured). But you won't have any specificity. (as none of the no-cancer cases were identified)

if this is the case, you might consider adding weights, to your not-majority category (here non-caner) to actually predict values and not just the majority category).

Answer (score 1):

You have two classes? Maybe classification is the wrong tool, and you should at least try probability modeling and estimation. One possibility then is logistic regression.  See [Why isn't Logistic Regression called Logistic Classification?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127042/why-isnt-logistic-regression-called-logistic-classification).  Then you will get estimated probabilities for each case, and can eventually decide afterwards on probability thresholds for classification. Those thresholds do not need to be constant, they can depend on individual case costs.  See also [Logistic Regression Model Validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105298/logistic-regression-model-validation)   and   [Using proper scoring rule to determine class membership from logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109851/using-proper-scoring-rule-to-determine-class-membership-from-logistic-regression).

Comment: I think, with no offense to the OP, the OP's post is a good example of what's going on in "machine learning". Very minimal understanding of statistics and the methods they're employing. When errors come up, the user has limited understanding of how things are done or how to begin diagnosing the problem. We need more statisticians teaching the "ML" crowd.